# Communicating to user that content is associated with a specific record?

Tags: usability, navigation, user-expectation, modal-windows

Lets say a main page provides navigation to two sections: Doing X and Doing Y.  Doing X is associated with a single record, however, Doing Y is associated with zero to many records.  Upon clicking <kbd>Do Y</kbd>, they will navigate to the last viewed Y page, and if there currently aren't any Ys, one will be created.  Alternatively, they can click one of the individual <kbd>Ys</kbd> in the "List of Ys".

Upon arriving at the Y1 page, the user can do their business.  They can also go to <kbd>Do X</kbd>, navigate to another Y, add a new Y, or delete the currently viewed Y. There is also extra content associated with Y1 which typically they will not wish to view or edit.  I've used <kbd>Open Dialog Module for Y1</kbd> for them to be able to access.

This dialog is getting kind of busy, and I wish to get rid of it and do things differently.  Without using a dialog, how can I allow the user to view and edit content, and know it is associated with a given record (i.e. Y1)?  How must the "Do X Menu Do Y Menu" change to support this?

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDIeH9.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Comment: Your question is quite difficult to understand (at least for me ;) ). Could you rephrase it with less abstraction? Maybe by replacing X and Ys by real world stuff or examples?

Answer (score 1):

For X, they go directly to the X page, and manage it. You are not exposing the edit/delete for X, so why expose it for Y?

What about:

• Do X (button)

• Do Y (dropdown: last Y page viewed, add new Y page, other existing Y page, other existing Y page, etc.)

The button and dynamic drop down could be included for each instance.